# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ICacheManager, key "Cache Manager"

Tags: c#, .net, caching, unity-container, enterprise-library

I seem to have hit a wall here and would appreciate some help from anyone who is able to on this one. I am not exactly sure what the error message below means. I am using the Caching Block of Enterprise Pattern Services but I keep running in to the problem below. I downloaded the latest version and tried stepping through to the issue but I can't seem to pin the exact problem and I need help please. Thanks in advance

```
Test method WorldBank.Service.Business.UnitTest.TopicsManagerTest.Call_Children_out_of_schoolTest threw exception: 
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ICacheManager, key "Cache Manager" ---> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager", name = "Cache Manager".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager,WuCache
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?


Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\DynamicMethod\Creation\DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.cs: line 209
BuildUp_Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager(IBuilderContext )
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\DynamicMethod\DynamicMethodBuildPlan.cs: line 37
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\BuildPlanStrategy.cs: line 43
Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\StrategyChain.cs: line 110
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs: line 511
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs: line 515
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs: line 173
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityServiceLocator.cs: line 64
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs: line 49
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs: line 53
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs: line 103
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheFactory.InnerGetCacheManager(String cacheManagerName) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Caching\Src\Caching\CacheFactory.cs: line 66
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(String cacheManagerName) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\Caching\Src\Caching\CacheFactory.cs: line 53
WorldBank.Service.Business.ResponseManager.Get_w_Utility() in C:\SOOfficialPiece\WorldBank.Service.Business\ResponseManager.cs: line 42
WorldBank.Service.Business.ResponseManager..ctor() in C:\SOOfficialPiece\WorldBank.Service.Business\ResponseManager.cs: line 34
WorldBank.Service.Business.ResponseManager.getResponseObjectJSON(Int32 perpage, Object results, Boolean doDeepRetrieval) in C:\SOOfficialPiece\WorldBank.Service.Business\ResponseManager.cs: line 68
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
WorldBankBusiness.Topics.TopicsManager.Call_Children_out_of_school(PersonType persontype, EnrollmentType enrollmenttype, String countrycode) in C:\SOOfficialPiece\WorldBank.Service.Business\TopicsManager.cs: line 39
WorldBank.Service.Business.UnitTest.TopicsManagerTest.Call_Children_out_of_schoolTest() in C:\SOOfficialPiece\WorldBank.Service.Business.UnitTest\TopicsManagerTest.cs: line 88
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The Caching Application Block requires some configuration information to be present in the app/web.config before it can be used (AFAIK, unfortunately it is tough to find documentation stating otherwise). Without that configuration info, the following code will cause that same exception to be thrown as you are seeing:

```
var cm = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("MyCacheManager");
```

In order to get a `CacheManager`, you need to define the `CacheManager` in your app.config or web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="cachingConfiguration" 
                 type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="MyCacheManager">
        <cacheManagers>
           <add name="MyCacheManager" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
                expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" 
                maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="50000" 
                numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="1000"  
                backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />
        </cacheManagers>
        <backingStores>
            <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
                 name="NullBackingStore" />
        </backingStores>
    </cachingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

Once you add the configuration values, you should be able to get a valid `CacheManager` from the `CacheFactory`. The [post](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/02/25/2814.aspx) also has some more information that might help you.

It is worth noting that if you are using .NET 4.0, for non web apps you can use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) (in the `System.Runtime.Caching` namespace) which provides similar functionality but does not require all of this configuration. And for web apps you can of course use the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) class in `System.Web.Caching`.

Comment: I am using similar configuration as in your sample. Diffidence is that I use IsolatedStorageBackingStore. It was working till now. What is commonly causing this error.

Comment: The error comes from Unity (Unity is a IoC library), which the Caching application block makes use of. Whenever you get "*** is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?" errors from Unity, it usually means that a type mapping hasn't been registered with Unity, either in code or through a config file. I don't have enough information to say why your code would stop working, but you should post a separate question and provide as much detail as possible if you want help.

Comment: It's been so long since this answer was given, but I should ask: When I add this to my App.config file, the service becomes unstartable, it gives "error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion". What can be the reason?

Comment: Hard to say. If you have the source and compile the service to run as a console app you should get a more detailed error message.

Comment: can you tell me what is the database structure required for using data cache store