# .net 4 issues with EnterpriseLibrary.Caching

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, caching, enterprise-library

In .net 4 website, I am making use of the Enterprise Library Caching assembly (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.dll, version 4.0.0.0).

When I try to get one of my caches using the method

```
CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("MyCacheManager")
```

, the .net runtime throws the following exception:

**The current build operation (build key Build Key[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.ICacheManager, MyCacheManager]) failed: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (Strategy type Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.ConfiguredObjectStrategy, index 2)**

Here is the full stack trace:

==============================================================================

**at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp(IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies, IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.Builder.BuildUp[TTypeToBuild](IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetime, IPolicyList policies, IStrategyChain strategies, Object buildKey, Object existing)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IReadWriteLocator locator, ILifetimeContainer lifetimeContainer, String id, IConfigurationSource configurationSource)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(String cacheManagerName)
   at MyProduct.MyProductDAL.MyProductDAL..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\Users\Yosief.Kesete\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProduct\MyProductDAL\MyProductDAL.cs:line 39**

================================================================================

I am developing using VS 2010 on a 64-bit Windows 7 Professional PC. My site is hosted in IIS 7.5. I've also added references to the rest of the assemblies that go along with the caching assembly, such as :

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll v4.0.0.0

Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll v2.1.0.0

Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll v2.0.414.0

etc...

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wired this up in the web.config?  I believe there is a section that must be present in order to find the correct Implementation.  The link below shows a loose example.

Moreover, I don't like editing this stuff by hand.  The Enterprise Library Configuration Manager will allow you to point and click to wire everything up in a pretty interface.

If you upgrade to version 5.x the user interface for the tool is even better.  highly recommended.

[related post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234076/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-icachemanager-key)

Comment: Hi Rob. I had added all the necessary settings in App.config file of one of my class projects. I went with version 4.1 of Ent Lib and had to add the caching settings in the web.config of my website as well. Now everything works!! Thanks for the help.