# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ICacheManager, key \"\""

Tags: c#, .net, caching, enterprise-library

I searched in google but i did not find solution to resolve that error. I am trying to create instance of Cache Manager but getting exception. I used Enterprise library 5.0. I could not find my issue. I am totally stuck. Any hints is appreciable.

```
ICacheManager cachManager = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ICacheManager>();
```

or

```
var cm = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("Cache Manager");
```

Config Info.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="cachingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Configuration.CacheManagerSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>

<cachingConfiguration defaultCacheManager="Cache Manager">
  <cacheManagers>
    <add name="Cache Manager" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.CacheManager, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" expirationPollFrequencyInSeconds="60" maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging="10000" numberToRemoveWhenScavenging="10" backingStoreName="NullBackingStore" />

  </cacheManagers>
  <backingStores>
    <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.BackingStoreImplementations.NullBackingStore, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.505.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="NullBackingStore" />
  </backingStores>
</cachingConfiguration>
```

Comment: Is the configuration deployed in web.config or appName.exe.config?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987356/enterprise-library-exception-activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-insta or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234076/activation-error-occured-while-trying-to-get-instance-of-type-icachemanager-key

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I upgraded from v. 5.0.414.0 to version 5.0.505.0. In my case I had to make sure the following is executed before calling `CacheFactory.GetCacheManager(..)` and it worked ok again.

```
     // first call this
     Container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
     // and then
     ICacheManager cacheManager = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager("Cache Manager");
```